# Finding the index of a substring in an existing string without IndexOf method

Tags: java

Currently trying to find a little information on how to find an index of a substring in an existing string. For instance if my String was "HelloWorld" and my Substring passed to my method was "world" the return index would be 5. I don't want to use the indexOf method simply because I want to actually learn how the indexOf method actually works from scratch.

```
public class TestMiniString
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      String n1 = new String("Helloworld, welcome");
      System.out.println(n1.findIndexOf("wo"));
      System.out.println(n1.findIndexOf("we"));
      System.out.println(n1.findIndexOf("llo"));

}

public class MiniStr
{
   private String str;


   public MiniStr(String x)
   {
      this.str = x;
   }

     public int findIndexOf(String x)
       {



       }
}
```

Comment: What is difference between asking SO and looking at the source code?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to do something like this..
Edited: this should check if there is a substring in your objects string which is equal to the parameter, and if yes returns the starting index, otherwise return -1

```
   public class TestMiniString {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           MiniStr n1 = new MiniStr("Helloworld");
           System.out.println(n1.findIndexOf("wo"));

    }

    public class MiniStr {
      private String str;

      public MiniStr(String x){
        this.str = x;
      }

      public getStr() {
         return this.str;
      }

       public int findIndexOf(String sub) {

          for (int i=0; i<getStr().length(); i++) {
              if (getStr().charAt(i) == sub.charAt(0)) {
                  int sumEq = 1;
                  for (int j=1; j<sub.length(); j++) {
                     if (sub.charAt(j) != getStr().charAt(i+j)) break;
                     else sumEq++;
                  }
                  if (sumEq == sub.length()) return i;
              }
          }
          return -1; //in case it is not an actual substring
       }
    }
```

Comment: Of course you can change the code to check for upper & lowercase, I just suggested a simple method.

Comment: doesn't work, unless `sub` is 1 char only (also `toCharArray()` unnecessarily copies the contents of `myString` to a new array - using `length()` and `charAt()` would avoid that)

Comment: @Maral Kay, I meant to add I would just like to use the basic string class methods length(), equals() and charAt()

Comment: you are right about unnecessary array, but why does sub need to be 1 char?

Comment: I edited the answer only using charAt() and length(), is this something like what you are looking?

Comment: @MaralKay your close, I am only passing one parameter to my method though.

Comment: @MaralKay think about what `findIndex("other", "one other")` would return using your code. Then you'll see why it only works when sub has only one character.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException you are right, they would have to do the check for the rest of the substring too..

Comment: @MaralKay so does this code check for just the first letter or that actual substring?

Comment: @hotrod28 yes, it only checks for the first letter, we would have to add checks for the next letters too, I'll update the answer asap

Comment: @MaralKay i just edited my code a little more to help with the process as well I added a "we" therefore landing it in a different place for the index

Comment: @hotrod28 didn't have the time to run the code, may need a little fix, but the logic seems okay to me so far.. hope it helps anyway!

Comment: @hotrod28 please let me know if this solution is functional or helpful

Answer (score -1):

You can learn how indexOf method actually works in here 
[ECMAScript 5.1 (ECMA-262)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.14)

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't encourage answers that merely link to external sites. This is due to the potential for links to be broken for future seekers. Please provide a full explanation in the answer itself.

Comment: Also, this link is to a different method in a different language that does something different even though it has the same name.